# How does Spotify customize the media playback controls on iOS?

Tags: ios, mpmediaplayercontroller, control-center

Spotify on iOS has a very interesting Control Center integration. Notice the hamburger button below.

[image: Hamburger]

The same thing is on the lock screen!

[image: lock screen]

How do they do those? Is there an API in MPMediaCenter or something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Yes, there is an API for that**

Looking at the instructions found in the apple docs regarding [remote control events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH7-SW6) you get two classes `MPRemoteCommand` and `MPRemoteCommandCenter` highlighted. Looking up [MPRemoteCommandCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPRemoteCommandCenter_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPRemoteCommandCenter/ratingCommand) will show you there are a multitude of commands like `likeCommand` or `dislikeCommand` you can add handlers for. Adding handlers to those commands causes them beeing displayed in the control center.

Below is some all-in-one code achieving pretty much exactly the same results shown on your screenshots:

```
- (void)showCustomizedControlCenter {
    /* basic audio initialization */
    NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
    self.player.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [self.player play];

    /* registering as global audio playback */
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

    /* the cool control center registration */
    MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
    [commandCenter.playCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent *event) {
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
    }];
    [commandCenter.dislikeCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent *event) {
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
    }];
    [commandCenter.likeCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent *event) {
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
    }];
    [commandCenter.nextTrackCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent *event) {
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
    }];

    /* setting the track title, album title and button texts to match the screenshot */ 
    commandCenter.likeCommand.localizedTitle = @"Thumb Up";
    commandCenter.dislikeCommand.localizedTitle = @"Thumb down";

    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter* info = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
    NSMutableDictionary* newInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [newInfo setObject:@"Mixtape" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    [newInfo setObject:@"Jamie Cullum" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];

    info.nowPlayingInfo = newInfo;
}
```

In addition to writing the code you need to

- add `AVFoundation` to your project
- `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` and `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`
- activate the Background Modes `"Audio and AirPlay"` in the app settings.

[image]
[image]