# iOS any way to debug apple app

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering, ios9

For iOS, is there any way to debug an apple app? Just to see what it does behind the scenes? I want to debug the apple music app.

I am asking this because I want to know how is apple able to use the "heart" button lock screen control in iOS 9. I can't seem to find any documentation on this. I understand this is reverse engineering and this may not be allowed.

Comment: I don't believe non-Apple developers are able to modify the elements on the lock screen. Apple, being Apple, can do what they want.

Comment: Regarding the heart or basically any modification to the media playback and / control center, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265813/how-does-spotify-customize-the-media-playback-controls-on-ios/30266060#30266060) i gave a while back which might be applicable to your situation.

Comment: You can use Jailbreak and some Cydia tweaks.

Comment: In many countries reverse engineering is illegal.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad srsly??? In what country for example? I srsly doubt that - why would you not be allowed to?

Comment: @luk2302 - See Wikipedia's "reverse engineering" entry.  Both the USA and European Union seem to have laws against it except when used for interoperability.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad hmmm..didn't know that. how do jailbreaks do it then when jailbreaking is legal?

Comment: @luk2302 Of course it is very complex, but there are laws prohibiting reverse engineering in many cases.

Comment: @PranoyC I did not say that it is illegal in any case, esp. if you have "a good reason" to do so. (Obviously I do not know the country you are acting in, so I cannot say whether it is allowed to you at all.) It is a very complex subject. However, what you try is RE for "copy to compete". This is the "worst" form of RE, because a competitor (you) simply tries to "steal" a technical solution to catch up competition. Even this may allowed in some countries, in others it isn't. I just wanted to give you a pointer to a potential risk. This is, why I wrote a comment, no answer.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad yes, thanks! I am from Canada and I looked it up and it's very complex to decide if it's legal or not. Ofcourse SO is the wrong place for me to ask about legality anyway. And no, I doubt it's considered copying to compete. I was more so asking because usually Apple is very good with documentation but I thought that since that's a new feature, I am not looking for the right place for documentation. I will have to wait for the docs to get updated completely for iOS 9. For the time being I did see a bit other docs for another new button on their lock screen so I will just use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse engineering is a violation of the [iOS SOFTWARE LICENSE AGREEMENT](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/iOS81.pdf).

> (d) You may not, and you agree not to or enable others to, copy (except as expressly permitted by this
>   License), decompile, reverse engineer, disassemble, attempt to derive the source code of, decrypt,
>   modify, or create derivative works of the iOS Software or any services provided by the iOS Software or
>   any part thereof (except as and only to the extent any foregoing restriction is prohibited by applicable
>   law or by licensing terms governing use of open-source components that may be included with the iOS
>   Software).

That being said; you can find in this [talk by Conrad Kramer](https://realm.io/news/conrad-kramer-reverse-engineering-ios-apps-lyft/), informations on tools for iOS reverse engineering like Charles, cycrypt, IDA and dumdecrypted .

Note that many of those tools are only available for jailbroken devices.

Happy hacking :)

Comment: This is no answer to his Q. Beside this the legal binding of such license agreements differ from country to country.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer as it informs me of the implications of what I am trying to do and it also gives hints on possible answers. Thanks both of you!

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad The talk from Conrad Kramer that I linked gives him some hints about how to achieve reverse engineering in iOS.
However, I agree with you that this is not a full answer because stackoverflow is not the place for non-legal stuff but I still gave him a resource about "debugging an apple app" as the OP asked.
Nonetheless, the OP wants to reverse engineer a feature from the lock screen that is only available for Apple's "Music" app so with a private API. And private API are harder to reverse engineer.
Doing so only for a Heart button is not really a good idea.